# iterate on rows of dataframe with conditional flag value in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, loops

I'm doing a cross-check between 2 dataframes to assign a value to a flag. If a specific key is present in both dataframes with a different value, the flag will be set to "change" for that row. If the value is the same, the flag will be set to "no change". However if a specific key is present more than once in only one of the 2 dataframes, then the value of the flag will be "add". Let me give an example to make it clearer:

**df 1**:

| key | value | key value present in df 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abcd | 1 | False |
| wxyz | 5 | True |

**df 2:**

| key | value | key value present in df 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abcd | 2 | False |
| wxyz | 5 | True |

Then the result will be for dataframe 1:

**df 1**:

| key | value | key value present in df 2 | xcheck_flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abcd | 1 | False | change |
| wxyz | 5 | True | no change |

To get this result I use the following logic:

```
def changeType(df1):
    def condition_check(row):
            if (row['key value present in df 2'] == False):
                    return 'change'
            else:
                    return 'no change'
    df1['xcheck_flag']= df1.apply(condition_check, axis=1)
```

Now this is rather straightforward, right? Well I have a complication which I haven't been able to solve, yet.

**Imagine the following use case**:

**df 1**:

| key | value | key value present in df 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abcd | 1 | False |
| wxyz | 5 | True |
| abcd | 3 | False |

**df 2:**

| key | value | key value present in df 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abcd | 2 | False |
| wxyz | 5 | True |

In this case, the key abcd appears twice in df 1 and only once in df 2. If this happen, I need to apply the following logic when doing the cross-dataframe check: the first time I will match the key with dataframe 2, then set the value of the flag to change like in previous case; the second time we match the value, then set the flag to "additional change". It doesn't matter which row from df 1 gets assigned the value "change" or "additional". The only condition is that when you have such a case, only one key-value gets assigned with "change" and then all the others that might happen get assigned with "additional"

This give us:

**df 1**:

| key | value | key value present in df 2 | xcheck_flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abcd | 1 | False | change |
| wxyz | 5 | True | no change |
| abcd | 3 | True | additional change |

I've been trying to adapt my initial function to include this behaviour but without success.

If you have any hint, it would be greatly welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['abcd', 'wxyz', 'abcd'], 'value': [1, 5, 3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['abcd', 'wxyz'], 'value': [2, 5]})
df1['key_duplicated'] = df1.duplicated('key', keep='first')
df3 = df1.join(df2.set_index(['key']), rsuffix='_2', on=['key'])
```

which gives you a dataframe which I think contains all the columns you need to calculate the flags you're interested in:

```
    key    value  key_duplicated  value_2
0  abcd        1           False        2
1  wxyz        5           False        5
2  abcd        3            True        2
```

note if the key is not present in df2 value_2 will be NaN.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be using a dictionary to store the number of occurrences of each key:

```
def check(key, value, df2):
    flag = ''
    if seen[key] > 0:
        flag = 'additional change'
    else:
        if value == df2[df2['key']==key]['value'].tolist()[0]:
            flag = 'no change'
        else:
            flag = 'change'
    seen[key] += 1
    return flag

seen = {k: 0 for k in df1['key'].tolist()}   
df1['flag'] = df1.apply(lambda row: check(row['key'], row['value'], df2), axis=1)
```